# get imageView from recyclelview android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design

i use recycleview for show data from database, everythink work well but i get problem when i try to change my imageView drawable when the imageView has clicked,i work like stackOverflow does when i'm doing vote up so the value of vote to be +1, i have  flow like this, i have 2 imageView,when imageView1 has clicked imageView1 change drawable to activeImage.png, and the other side imageView2 (in same row)change drawable to diactivatedImage.png, i have tried many code but not work properly, this my code

```
public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected  ImageView imgVoteUp,imgVoteDown;
    protected  TextView vote;

    public ContactViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        imgVoteUp= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.gf_imgVoteUp);
        imgVoteDown= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.gf_imgVoteDown);
        vote = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.gf_tvjmlVote);
    }

}


@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, int i) {
        final GfContactInfo ci = contactList.get(i);
        Picasso.with(ctx)
                .load(ctx.getString(R.string.photo) + ci.pp)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.gada_photo)
                .error(R.drawable.gada_photo)
                .into(contactViewHolder.gambarPP);

        contactViewHolder.imgVoteUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vote("idPosid","up",12,v);
            }
        });

        contactViewHolder.imgVoteUp.setImageResource(R.drawable._icon_up);
        contactViewHolder.imgVoteDown.setImageResource(R.drawable._icon_down);

}

    private void vote(String posid,String sts,int jmlVote,View v){
        String votex="0";
        ImageView iVup=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.gf_imgVoteUp);
        ImageView iVdown=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.gf_imgVoteDown); //i get error here because this is null
        TextView tVoteCount=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.gf_tvjmlVote);
        if (sts.equalsIgnoreCase("up")) {
            if (iVup.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable._icon_up).getConstantState())) {
                if (iVdown.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable._icon_down_selected).getConstantState())) {
                    iVup.setImageResource(R.drawable._icon_up);
                } else {
                    iVup.setImageResource(R.drawable._icon_up_selected);
                }
                iVdown.setImageResource(R.drawable._icon_down);
                votex = "1";
                jmlVote+=1;

            } else {
                votex="-1";
                jmlVote-=1;
                iVup.setImageResource(R.drawable._icon_up);
                iVdown.setImageResource(R.drawable._icon_down);
            }
        }else{
            if (iVdown.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable._icon_down).getConstantState())) {
                if (iVup.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable._icon_up_selected).getConstantState())) {
                    iVdown.setImageResource(R.drawable._icon_down);
                } else {
                    iVdown.setImageResource(R.drawable._icon_down_selected);
                }
                iVup.setImageResource(R.drawable._icon_up);
                votex = "1";
                jmlVote+=1;

            } else {
                votex="-1";
                jmlVote-=1;
                iVup.setImageResource(R.drawable._icon_up);
                iVdown.setImageResource(R.drawable._icon_down);
            }
        }
        tVoteCount.setText(jmlVote+"");

    }
```

what should i do ? please help.

Comment: Where is imgVoteUp come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code passes in imgVoteUp as the View parameter to vote.  When you call findViewById it can't find imgVoteDown as it's not a child of imgVoteUp!

You need to change your vote method to accept the ViewHolder instead of the view so that you can get your references:

```
private void vote(String posid, String sts, int jmlVote, ContactViewHolder viewHolder) {

    ImageView iVup = viewholder.imgVoteUp;
    ImageView iVdown = viewholder.imgVoteDown;

    //...

}
```

Then in your onClick method you would call:

```
vote("idPosid", "up", 12, contactViewHolder);
```